# Inverse Laplace transform using convolutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\
  H(s)=\frac{s-5}{(s-3)(s-1)}
$$

The inverse Laplace transform of $\ H(s)$ is equal to $$\ f*g$$ I know if I used $\ \frac{1}{s-1}
 $ as $\ G(s)$ then its inverse laplace transform would be  $\ e^t $ but then how would I find $\ f(s) $ knowing that $\ F(s)=\frac{s-5}{s-3}$

If I were able to find $\ f(s) $ then I could evaluate $\ f*g $  which is $$ \int_0^t{f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau} $$ and complete the problem.

I understand the inverse Laplace transform of $\ H(s) $ can be solved easily with partial fractions but this is an exercise in convolutions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can write

$$F(s)=\frac{s-5}{s-3}=1-\frac{2}{s-3}$$

Then , $f(t)=\delta(t)-2e^{3t}u(t)$ and

$$\begin{align}
h(t)&=\int_{0}^t e^{t-t'}(\delta(t')-2e^{3t'})\,dt'\\\\
&=e^t-e^t(e^{2t}-1)\\\\
&=2e^t-e^{3t}
\end{align}$$

---

Note that partial fraction expansion makes things easier.  We simply write

$$H(s)=\frac{2}{s-1}-\frac{1}{s-3}$$

Comment: Ah, looking at your hint I see by rewriting (s-5)/[(s-3)(s-1)] as 1/(s-1)-2/[(s-3)(s-1)] I can simplify the problem and still solve it using convolutions on the second part

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark